# Miniming search in a 2-D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I 'm faced with a problem at school. The problem is: 
Given an 8*8 array. Suppose a "ghost" is hidden somewhere in the array.

The first time you visit the block in the array where the "ghost" is hidden, then the ghost moves to another random block. The algorithm terminates when the ghost is found 2 times.

The question is describe an algorithm to find the ghost in the least steps k possible.

For starters, I thought I should try something like Hamiltonian Path, if every block in the array is let's say a vertex,  but the complexity of this algorithm is too much.

Then, I thought about simple iterative Search which will be `O(n^2 - 1)`. Since, after the ghost is found for the first time, the same box will not be visited again.

Another way, would be to pick a random point in the array and start my linear search from there, but again this will be 'O(n^2 - 1)'.

This is really driving me crazy. Any suggestions?